# How to set up correctly environment variables for airflow using docker compose in Window 10 ? airflow-init_1 ERROR: AIRFLOW_UID not set

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I run `docker-compose up airflow-init` in cmd to deploy Airflow using the template given at [docker-compose.yaml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml), folder logs, plugins and dags are created:

```
C:\Users\Diego\Airflow>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4296-D163

 Directory of C:\Users\Diego\Airflow

09/18/2021  07:45 PM    <DIR>          .
09/18/2021  07:45 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/18/2021  07:45 PM                44 .env
09/18/2021  05:59 PM    <DIR>          dags
09/18/2021  05:52 PM             8,031 docker-compose.yaml
09/18/2021  07:44 PM    <DIR>          logs
09/18/2021  06:02 PM    <DIR>          plugins
               2 File(s)          8,075 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  22,549,196,800 bytes free
```

When the command is run, the Error given is:

```
C:\Users\Diego\Airflow>docker-compose up airflow-init
WARNING: The AIRFLOW_UID variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The AIRFLOW_GID variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating network "airflow_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "airflow_postgres-db-volume" with default driver
Creating airflow_redis_1    ... done                                                                                    Creating airflow_postgres_1 ... done                                                                                    Creating airflow_airflow-init_1 ... done                                                                                Attaching to airflow_airflow-init_1
airflow-init_1       | ERROR!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!
airflow-init_1       | Please follow these instructions to set AIRFLOW_UID and AIRFLOW_GID environment variables:
airflow-init_1       |     https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#initializing-environment
```

It seems to be an error while synchronizing access from docker to the folders, which is solved in Linux or mac by defining env variables file with `echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env` .

I tried to run the echo command, which leads to the .env file created in the directory, but this doesn't help to get airflow-init to run without the error, so this is only for Linux, the mounted volumes in container seems unable to use the windows filesystem user/group permissions, so the container and host computer don't have matching file permissions.

How to set up correctly environment variables for airflow using docker-compose in Window 10?

Docker Desktop 4.0.1
Steps:

- Get the file from yaml Airflow community webpage and place it in a directory
- Create folders folder logs, dags, plugins in same directory
- Run `docker-compose up airflow-init`

Answer (score 4):

You can manually create the .env file. Simply create a file that will contain two lines:

```
AIRFLOW_UID=50000
AIRFLOW_GID=0
```

Just make sure you save the file as text file in whatever editor you edit it. By default if you save it in Windows editor, it might be saved in not the right encoding ([http://www2.hawaii.edu/~jamess/textonly.htm](http://www2.hawaii.edu/%7Ejamess/textonly.htm))

BTW. As Airflow 2.1.4 (possibly even will be released today) you will not need that file for Windows. This has been fixed already but needs release - so you might even wait for 2.1.4 to be out.

Comment: Yep. 2.1.4 is out and it should solve the problem with creating the .env file (in short - you do not have to do it any more)

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html is where you can head to get the latest docker-compose

Comment: Thanks, The file .env as in the post solves the problem. I just tested the new file for 2.1.4, first I flush out the past images with ``` docker-compose down --volumes --remove-orphans ```, and get the new yaml file example in apache web page, but I still see some warnings WARNING: The AIRFLOW_UID variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. Although it runs without problem init and compose up, does the warning apply only to unix ?

Comment: yes. I think you should also see the warning explicitly mentioning linux when you run `init`